# Перегрузка operator[]

Tags: c++

Вот часть кода, помогите пожалуйста реализовать перегрузку оператора []

```
class Matrix
{
protected: 
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > Matr;
public:

    int* operator[](int n)
    {
        return Matr[n];     
    }

    Matrix(size_t n) : Matr(n, std::vector<int>(n))
    {
        if (n < 1)
        {
            throw Exception();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не думаю, что хорошо так менять вопрос.

Comment: Окей, я тогда перезалью лучше, извините

Comment: @ZolbergN да, просто задайте новый вопрос. ) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем варианте логичнее

```
vector<int>& operator[](size_t i)
{
    return Matr[i];
}
```

и соответствующая константная версия

```
const vector<int>& operator[](size_t i) const
{
    return Matr[i];
}
```

Ну, и, возможно, дописать проверки на выход за пределы диапазона...

Если ну совершенно необходимо возвращать `int*`, то `return &Matr[i][0];`

Answer (score 0):

Обычно этот оператор перегружается в виду двух функций для константного и не константного объектов. То есть обе функции следует включить в определение класса. Например,

```
std::vector<int> & operator[]( size_t n )
{
    return Matr[n];     
}

const std::vector<int> & operator[]( size_t n ) const
{
    return Matr[n];     
}
```